# Approximation of the values of a vector with another vector

Tags: matlab

I need to approximate the values from the first column to the closest values from the second column (I understand that a threshold is needed, it could be 0.0090) and save the indexes.
I have being using the following:

```
[ms, ix] = sort(m(:));
[r, c] = ind2sub(size(m),ix); 
proximity_threshold = 0.0090; 
ind = (diff(ms)<proximity_threshold);  
ind(end+1)=0;
n=0;
nn=0;
while n<numel(ix) 
    n=n+1;
    nn=nn+1;
    if ind(n) & c(n)~=c(n+1)
        a(nn,c(n))=ms(n);
        a(nn,c(n+1))=ms(n+1);
        n=n+1;
    else
        a(nn,c(n))=ms(n);
    end
end
```

But I am not happy with this implementation. It approximates the values, but it returns a matrix of size (900 x 2) and I want a matrix with the same size as the original one (500x2).

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like `interp1` using `'nearest'` method should work well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nispio's answer is good, but the matching is much more complex than necessary.  The `interp1` function can be used to map values to lookup table entries.

Trim x_t according to nispio's method:

```
x_t = x_t(1:find(x_t~=0,1,'last'));
```

Now we use the function designed for table lookup.

```
idx = interp1(x, 1:numel(x), x_t, 'nearest');
```

Finally, get the found values, same as nispio:

```
y = x(idx);
```

Comment: Hi @BenVoigt, I have tried your suggestion and it works very well :) Thank you for your help!!! I was struggling with this matter and now I have 2 excellent ways to solve it! Thanks again.

Comment: Just a lite question @BenVoigt, what does actually matlab with the  commandos 'last' and 'nearest'?

Comment: @Sergio: Those are strings which are specially recognized by `find()` and `interp1()`, respectively.  You'll find such magic strings in the documentation of every function.

Comment: +1; I didn't realize that `interp1` could be used that way. I guess it isn't obvious because it doesn't really match my idea of what 'interpolation' means. If I had to give it a name,  it seems more like a quantization operation.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can skip the matrix `m`.  It is a less-than-optimal way to go about the problem in this case. Also, get rid of the zeros at the end of `x_t`.  They are not necessary.  If you need help trimming the zeros off the end, try this:

```
x_t = x_t(1:find(x_t~=0,1,'last'));
```

Now, for the matching.  You can find the closest match in `x_t` to the elements of `x` with the following:

```
B = bsxfun(@minus, x_t(:), x(:).'); %'
[idx,~] = find(bsxfun(@eq, abs(B), min(abs(B))));
y = x_t(idx);
```

Now the approximations of `x` are found in `y`, with corresponding index found in `idx`.

## Explanation

---

```
bsxfun(@minus, x, y);
```

This will take a column vector `x` and subtract it by the each or the elements of the row vector `y`. For example,

```
>> x = [3 6 9 12].'; y = [1 2 3];
>> ans = bsxfun(@minus, x, y);

ans =

     2     1     0
     5     4     3
     8     7     6
    11    10     9
```

Or in other words, what is happening is:

ans =

```
 (3-1)   (3-2)   (3-3)
 (6-1)   (6-2)   (6-3)
 (9-1)   (9-2)   (9-3)
(12-1)  (12-2)  (12-3)
```

---

```
bsxfun(@eq, A, min(A));
```

This finds the locations in the columns of the matrix `A` where the column minimum resides. It returns a logical matrix (ones and zeros). For example,

```
>> A = [ 1  2  3  4;
      3  3  6  5;
      2  2  0  7;
      5  1  8  5;
      4  5  2  6];

>> ans = bsxfun(@eq, A, min(A))

ans =

    1   0   0   1
    0   0   0   0
    0   0   1   0
    0   1   0   0
    0   0   0   0
```

---

```
[idx,~] = find(A);
```

The `find` command searches for all of the non-zero elements of the matrix `A`.  Normally you would call it as `[row, col] = find(A);` to get back the rows and columns, but since I am only interested in the row, I use `~` to tell Matlab that I don't want to keep the column value.

---

```
y = x(idx);
```

This creates a new vector `y` which contains the elements of `x` as referenced by `idx`.  Since I already found the indices that minimize the error, I use them to pluck out the `x` values at those indices.

---

**Putting it all together:**

At a high level, the code does the following:

The matrix `B` compares every value of `x` (columns) with every value of `x_t` (rows)

For every column (`x`) of `B`, find the row (`x_t`) which minimizes the error.

Knowing the rows we can extract the `x_t` values directly using the row indices.

Hope this helps!

## Update

I realized that if a value of `x` was exactly the same distance between two values of `x_t` then you would end up with a vector that was too long, because multiple answers will be selected.  Below is the fix to the problem.

```
B = bsxfun(@minus, x_t(:), x(:).'); %'
[idx,col] = find(bsxfun(@eq, abs(B), min(abs(B))));
idx(1 < sum(triu(bsxfun(@eq, col(:), col(:).')))) = []; %'
y = x_t(idx);
```

Basically what the added line does is throw away any index values that do not correspond to the first match in a given column.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @nispio, I will give it a try! but as you can see -through my matrix m and my zeros- I am just a jr. in the programing world. In other words the code is to advanced for my to understand it. Thanks again. PS. if I need to go the other way and fin the closest match in x to the elements of x_t; I just have to change in B =...x_t(:),x(:) with --> B =...x(:),x_t(:) right?

Comment: Yes, you can do it the other way around as long as you replace **all** occurrences of `x` with `x_t` and vice versa.

Comment: The code works excellent @nispio! Thank you very much for the explanation! :)

Comment: There is a small caveat that I did not bother to work around.  If one of your `x` values lands perfectly between two `x_t` values such that the difference between them is equal, you will get a `y` matrix that is longer than your original `x` matrix because it accepted two matches instead of just one.

Comment: Ok, I will be carefully in checking the size of y every time i use your code. Nevertheless, this will not be a problem for me.

Comment: @SergioSarmiento: Famous last words.  ;-)